# Get Portion of String

Tags: java, android

I need to get the values after "Swap:".

[image]

I've already developed a method to get the output from a shell command so I have a string that contains everything you see in the picture but now from the string I want to get ONLY the value after the Swap: How can i do this? These value are variable and can be even all three 0.

Comment: How do you store the Strings/how does the method return the information? Is the three lines from the image stored in three different Strings or in just one?

Comment: Please don't post images for text-only content. Put the text directly in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the text stored in a `String` called `textContent`. Assuming the Swap-line is the last part of your String, then you could do something like this:

```
int index = textContent.indexOf("Swap:");

index += "Swap:".length();
textContent.subString(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] stringParts = text.substring(text.indexOf("Swap:") + 5).trim().split("( )+");

int[] parts = new int[stringParts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < stringParts.length; i++)
    parts[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringParts[i]);
```

It will fill an integer array will the values after the "Swap" part.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already stored the output of the shell command, you simply need to do some string manipulation to search and extract the relevant information. The following particular string manipulation methods might be of interest to you: [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29), [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29), and [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

Below is a simple example code on how to extract the value under the `total`'s column using the above String methods:

```
public class ShellOutput {

    public ShellOutput() {
        final String extract = "Swap:"; // the keyword to search

        String shellOutput = "Swap:          75692        29657              0"; // your shell output
        int position = shellOutput.indexOf(extract); // get the position of the Swap: text
        if (position != -1) {
            String swapLine = shellOutput.substring(position + extract.length()); // remove everything except the swap line
            String numbers = swapLine.trim(); // assuming they are spaces, otherwise do some operations to remove tabs if used

            int firstSpace = numbers.indexOf(' '); // get the first space or change to a tab character if it is used

            String totalNumber = numbers.substring(0, firstSpace); // remove up to the first found after the number

            System.out.println("Total = " + totalNumber);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No '" + extract + "' segment found.");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ShellOutput();
    }
}
```

**Output:** Total = 75692